# PHP rename() file_exists()

Tags: php, rename

How can I use PHP to move a file?

Code:

```
if( file_exists($imageLocation) )
  echo "file exists on server";

rename($imageLocation, $imageNewLocation);
```

Output:

> file exists on server
>   Warning: rename(/home/images/file1.jpg,/home/newloc/renamed.jpg) [function.rename]: No such file or directory in /home/apps/images/add.php on line 81

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When moving files, `rename()` can only move them to a folder that already exists. It can not create new parent directories on the fly.

Make sure `/home/newloc` exists. If it doesn't, use `mkdir()` to create it.

Comment: `rename() can't create folders. It can only move files to an existing folder.`
This is misleading at best.[PHP: rename - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) specifically states
>rename — Renames a file or directory  If it already existed... we wouldn't be *rename*ing it would we?

Comment: @WallabyKid true, clarified